# Batch to copy folder with partial name of the origin

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way from the command line to copy a folder from which i only know part of its name and name the new folder based on the 1st one? And then zip it.

eg.

```
xcopy "c:\sys\my-folder-web-1.1" "c:\temp\my-folder-1.1.web" /E /H /I
7z.exe a -r "c:\end\my-folder.7z" "c:\temp\my-folder-1.1.web"
```

Basically i want to use part of the name and put it in the end of the folder (like an extension - .web)
I wanna do a batch file that works dynamically so the "1.1" could be 1.2, etc, but the "web" part is always the same, like :

```
original folder        ->  result folder
my-folder-web-1.1      ->  my-folder-1.1.web
my-folder-web-1.2      ->  my-folder-1.2.web
my-folder-web-5.1      ->  my-folder-5.1.web
my-folder-web-67.1XPTO ->  my-folder-67.1XPTO.web
```

There would be no input parameter since the batch would work for any folder with this kind of syntax.

Any help?

Comment: What do you have as input parameter here? path "c:\sys\my-folder-web-1.1" ?

Answer (score 0):

We can utilize **DIR PATH*** expansion here:

```
@echo off
set INPUT_PATH="c:\sys\my-folder-web-"
for /f "delims=" %%G IN ('DIR %INPUT_PATH%* /A:D /B') DO (
    xcopy "%%~fG" c:\temp\"%%~nG.web" /E /H /I
    rem work with c:\temp\"%%~nG.web" here
)
echo Done!
```

Note that tilde substitutions based on path can only be applied to one-sided variable, i.e to command line inputs and FOR loop variable. Read more about tilde substitutions [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Percent_tilde)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f %%q IN ('dir /b /ad u:\sys\*-*-web-*.*') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1-3*delims=-" %%a IN ("%%q") DO (
  ECHO xcopy "%~1" "u:\temp\%%~nxa-%%b-%%d.web" /E /H /I
  ECHO 7z.exe a -r "u:\end\%%~nxa-%%b.7z" "u:\temp\%%~nxa-%%b-%%d.web"
 )
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a start. Not really sure what your format actually is. I implemented it on my `U:` drive and have simply `ECHO`ed the constructed commands.